# how to locking file in vscode?

Tags: npm, tfs, visual-studio-code, tfvc

**Notes:** I tried all questions & answers related this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no the success. So please read my question thoroughly.

I have to Add my Project to Source control in VSCode. I have Checkout File Then File Icon Unlock another Wise icon is a lock. but I don't Know How to achieve this Anybody Can Help me.

**I want all Sever File is Locked with icons.**

Below I attache screen Short without lock file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To connect TFS, you need to install [Visual Studio Team Services Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode)

Based on my test, **we cannot lock files with icons, there isn't such a built-in feature for now.**

> **The following are the current features supported by the extension:**
>
> - Execute all basic version control actions such as add, delete,    rename, move, etc.
> - View local changes and history for your files
> - Include and Exclude changes (and move files between the two states)
> - Merge conflicts from updates
> - Check-in and update local files
> - Associate work items to check-ins
> - Provides an integrated TFVC Output window
> - Support for a TFS proxy
> - Supports workspaces created with Visual Studio (via tf.exe) or the    JetBrains IDEs and Eclipse (via the Team Explorer Everywhere Command
>   Line Client)
>
> See [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/12/official-release-of-tfvc-support-for-visual-studio-code/) for more information.

However you can lock files using the **[tf lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/lock-command?view=vsts)** command (run command in TERMINAL)

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Just as I mentioned above, unfortunately no such a built-in feature for now, and I tried to find some extensions to achieve that, but no gain.

Unless you can write your own extension to achieve that. Please see the extension [**seti-icons**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qinjia.seti-icons) on MarkketPlace, and this article: [Customize Your VS Code Icon](https://dev.to/reverentgeek/customize-your-vs-code-icon-6gd), hope that helps.

Comment: @Sumit patel Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: i have already use this . my question is  i want to lock icon in server file

Comment: @Sumitpatel Unfortunately no such a built-in feature for now, and I tried to find some extensions to achieve that, but no gain. Unless you can write your own extension to achieve that. Please see the extension [**seti-icons**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qinjia.seti-icons) on MarkketPlace, and this article: [Customize Your VS Code Icon](https://dev.to/reverentgeek/customize-your-vs-code-icon-6gd), hope that helps.